# MinGW C++ vs VS2013 C++, performance difference

Tags: visual-c++, mingw32

I am developing a library for power systems simulation, for which the execution time is critical.

I created Netbeans (MinGW) and Visual studio projects.

I compiled the library in both environments and I created a project to run a main.cpp file using the library.

I found that, with the exact same code, the MinGW compiler produces a program that runs about twice as fast than the Visual studio one.

The visual studio one is compiled for 64 bits, while the MinGW is compiled for 32 bits.

Can anydoby explain to me why one is much faster that the other?

PS: the full code can be found at:https://sourceforge.net/p/fpotencia/code/ci/master/tree/

{EDIT}-----------------

VS output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: fPotencia, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Transformer.cpp
1>  Solver_ZBlockSubs.cpp
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(55): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(59): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(81): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(94): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(121): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(128): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(147): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(165): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(182): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(184): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\solver_zblocksubs.cpp(211): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Solution.cpp
1>  Shunt.cpp
1>  Load.cpp
1>  Line.cpp
1>  Generator.cpp
1>  ExternalGrid.cpp
1>  Circuit.cpp
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(125): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(132): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(155): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(162): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(460): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(463): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(466): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(469): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(506): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Bus.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\circuit.cpp(74): warning C4715: 'fPotencia::Circuit::find_bus' : not all control paths return a value
1>  fPotencia.vcxproj -> D:\C++\fPotencia\Windows\VisualStudio\fPotencia\Debug\fPotencia.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: fPotencia_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  main.cpp
2>d:\c++\fpotencia\src\test\main.cpp(189): warning C4101: 'k' : unreferenced local variable
2>  fPotencia_test.vcxproj -> D:\C++\fPotencia\Windows\VisualStudio\fPotencia\Debug\fPotencia_test.exe
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Netbeans output:

```
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/C++/fPotencia/Windows/Netbeans/fPotencia_test'
"/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fpotencia_test.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/C++/fPotencia/Windows/Netbeans/fPotencia_test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/608944044
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/608944044/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -I../../../src -I../../../libs -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/608944044/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/608944044/main.o ../../../src/test/main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fpotencia_test build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/608944044/main.o ../fPotencia/dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libfpotencia.a
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/C++/fPotencia/Windows/Netbeans/fPotencia_test'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/C++/fPotencia/Windows/Netbeans/fPotencia_test'
```

Comment: Did you try Visual Studio 32bits and MinGW 64bits? JUst to know if the problem comes from the compiler or the target platform?

Comment: Well, MinGW is 32 bits only, I tryed installing the x64 version but I couldn't get it to work. And VS in 32 bits still produces a "slow" executable

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the compiler command line in both scenarios.

Comment: `Configuration: Debug Win32`.  Comparing perf on the non-optimized debug build is pointless.  It also isn't the 64-bit build.

Comment: I'm completely new to C++, could you be more explicit on what is it needed? Besides the x64 build looks exactly the same.

Comment: What was needed was to compare valid release-mode builds with optimised code - not debug builds, which can be as slow as they want to allow debugging info and support, and of course aren't required to exhibit the same _ratio_ of slowness vs release between different compilers. Also, MinGW is not 32-bit only: a perfectly functioning 64-bit version exists. I know it took them a while to get up to speed with w64, but I _think_ things were OK by late 2014.